# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'city0_.country_code' in 'field list' with SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, entity

Trying to create a simple SpringBoot application - Api with DataBase, using Gradle. When trying to get data from the Table, using api call, getting an exception in a Postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-01T12:45:40.218+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
    "path": "/api/demo/towns"
}
```

In the Idea having next exception:

> 2018-04-01 15:44:29.553 ERROR 17532 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column
>   'city0_.country_code' in 'field list' 2018-04-01 15:44:29.578 ERROR
>   17532 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet] with root cause
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'city0_.country_code' in 'field list'  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]  at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>   ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2168)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1489)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:307)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]   at
>   com.apidbdemo.controllers.DemoController.getTowns(DemoController.java:27)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_144]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_144]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]

I see that problem is with the CountryCode column, but don't understand, what is with it.
Using MySql DB, one table. It's structure:
[image]

Main entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="city")
public class City implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;


    @Column(name="CountryCode")
    private String countryCode;

    @Column(name="District")
    private String district;

    @Column(name="Population")
    private int population;

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    public City(String name, String countryCode, String district, int population){
        this.name = name;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.district = district;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public City(){

    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository("cityRepository")
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Integer> {
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/demo")
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("cityRepository")
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "towns",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = {MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
                    headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<City>> getTowns() {
        Iterable<City> list = cityRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<City>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the error message, Hibernate tries to read the column country_code, not CountryCode. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: But, in both, in table I have: CountryCode, and in entity i added an annotation: @Column(name="CountryCode"), why it searches for other column?

Comment: Everything is explained in the link I provided. Click it, and read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @JB Nizet answer, after I added property: `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` into `application.property` file, all is working. Thanks.